# Copy all console text to the clipboard

Tags: python, cmd, clipboard, pyautogui

I am working with some proprietary business software written in DB/C, a short-lived variant of COBOL over 20 years ago with no access to source code or useful documentation of any kind. I've been trying to automate some of our processes with python, and have written a handler object that can pass commands and send various key codes using pyautogui but I have reached a barrier where sometimes I need to rely on the output of the previous routine to decide when/whether to trigger the next. The software GUI runs in a console window, similar to ncurses.

How can I copy the entire contents of my console window to my clipboard? If there is a way to copy it directly to a local python variable that would be ideal; Once I have the screen text I can just match the part I need with a regex.

Here is my handler so far just to give you an idea:

```
import pyautogui
import time
import subprocess

class ECISession:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.openECI()
        self.login(username, password)

    def openECI(self):
        # Open ECI as a subprocess
        subprocess.Popen("F:\\ECI\\hp4\\test\\s.bat")

    def login(self, username, password):
        # Login to ECI Session with username and password
        time.sleep(15)
        pyautogui.write(username, interval=0.1)
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        pyautogui.write(password, interval=0.1)
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        pyautogui.write('Y')  # Make sure it ignores duplicate login

    @staticmethod
    def send(text='', supressEnter=False):
        # Send passed text to console and press enter unless specified to supress
        if text != '':
            pyautogui.write(text, interval=0.1)
        if supressEnter:
            pass
        else:
            pyautogui.press('enter')
            time.sleep(1)

    @staticmethod
    def sendF3(n=1):
        # Send F3 save key 1 time by default, n times if needed
        while n != 0:
            pyautogui.press('F3')
            n -= 1

    @staticmethod
    def sendF4(n=1):
        # Send F4 search key 1 time by default, n times if needed
        while n != 0:
            pyautogui.press('F4')
            n -= 1

    @staticmethod
    def readscreen():
        # return entire console window text
        pass
```

The readscreen() method is what I need to figure out. I just want to return the console content. I would just use the mouse to highlight the entire thing and press enter, but I have no way to make sure the window starts in the same place every time; It can't be maximized or it will crash since it expects an 80 column display with a specific font size.

FYI, the software in question is HealthPac by Eldorado Computing Incorporated. If any of you have used it you know the struggle. I would post some screenshots but it may be a HIPPA violation or something.

Comment: Can you do pyautogui ctrl a?

Comment: Nope. To copy normally I have to use edit > mark or highlight and enter like you would in a normal cmd window.